# A problem with "As... As"

Tags: sentence-construction, as

I have a problem with using the saying "as...as". I have read an example in the dictionary "You're as tall as your father", another is that "He doesn't earn as much as me", and it has another say "He doesn't earn as much as I do". I wonder if the first example can be said "You're as tall as your father is"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
The object pronoun is usually used.

- *You are as tall as **him**.*
- *You are tall as **he is**.*
- *<s>You are tall as he.</s>*

Comment: There are still people who argue, on the basis of your second example, that your third example (which you have struck out) is "correct" and your first is "incorrect". They are living in a world of their own.

Comment: My oxford gives that. I think one of them can be used  for written and another is for spoken?

Comment: @ColinFine Interesting. How do you use it then being a native speaker?

Comment: I could remember that my sister had told me about that. One of them is more common in spoken. But I cannot remember.

Comment: @Ustanak: I say "as him".