# find these as attractive a home as the rubble of the past

Tags: as

"So far we have used things like old car tires and rope, but we have a plan to carry out a more detailed study to test out a variety of artificial structures and see whether the sea creatures in the harbor find these as attractive a home as the rubble of the past. "

**Source : Oxford grammar book**

The sentence **"find these as attractive a home as the rubble of the past"** is so confusing that I cannot figure out what does it mean?

Could you please explain in more details?

Is there 'a fixed rule' for the following pattern:
"As + adjective + noun +as "

As I don't want to only memorize .I also want to know in more details to be able to understand such forms whenever I come across such structures.

Can I rewrite the sentence as following?

"So far we have used things like old car tires and rope, but we have a plan to carry out a more detailed study to test out a variety of artificial structures and see whether the sea creatures in the harbor **find these a home that is as attractive as the rubble of the past.** "

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A problem with "As... As"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81384/a-problem-with-as-as)

Comment: I disagree about the similarity with the possible duplicate. It would indeed be similar if the question or the answer included a sentence like "You are as tall **a man** as him."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... as ADJ a NOUN as {complement}

... as big a house as {complement}

... as big a house as *theirs*.

... as big a house as *money can buy*.

... as big a house as *is needed for a family with six kids*.

... as big a house as *always*.

... as attractive a home as the rubble of the past.

CLUNKY PARAPHRASES:

The home is *as attractive as* the rubble of the past is attractive.

The home's attractiveness = the attractiveness of the past's rubble

Comment: What does the phrase _attractiveness of the past's rubble_ mean? I couldn't understand it. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sea creatures have made homes in the rubble of the past (historical times) which fell or was dumped into the sea. Will today's junk prove to be just as attractive to them?

Comment: After reading the _context_ in the actual source, I came to know the meaning of it. Thank you.